# How to integrate getstat() api webrtc with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, webrtc, load-testing

I have to run a load test of around 1 hour using jmeter which needs to be integrated with getstat api webrtc to collect audio and video streaming metrics for this duration.

Any inputs who has worked on similar framework??

Answer (score 1):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So if by "getstat api" you mean [RTCPeerConnection.getStats()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/getStats) function the only way of obtaining it is using [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) which provides JMeter integration with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) browser automation framework. You can add another [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) which will kick off the real browser, collect WebRTC stats and store them into i.e. [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property, this way you will be able to add them into [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles)